# Как изьять из строки числа? С++

Tags: c++

> Дано натуральное число n. От данного числа вычтем сумму цифр этого
>   числа, от полученного числа опять вычтем сумму цифр образованного
>   числа и т. Д. Данную операцию над числом будем выполнять, пока
>   образовано число положительное. Сколько раз будем выполнять данную
>   операцию.

Так вот, я хочу сделать строку (а не число) и потом из неё тягать цифры..Можете подсказать как это воплотить в коде?

Comment: А можно задание перевести на русский или хотя бы на английский:)?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, Дано натуральное число n. От данного числа вычтем сумму цифр этого числа, от полученного числа опять вычтем сумму цифр образованного числа и т. Д. Данную операцию над числом будем выполнять, пока образовано число положительное. Сколько раз будем выполнять данную операцию.

Comment: @goodalien1125: Вот этот текст и положите в вопрос.

Comment: @goodalien1125, Это можно сделать без использования строк. [Получится проще и эффективнее](http://cpp.sh/7ghj)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, Да я знаю..но хотел попробовать так..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условно задачу можно разделить на несколько частей.
**Преобразование числа в строку**
В этом нам поможет `std::stringstream`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main(){
    int value = 123;
    std::stringstream sstream;
    sstream << value;

    std::cout << sstream.str() << std::endl; //123
}
```

**Перебор всех символов строки**
Строка это ничто иное как массив char. Перебирать символы можно при помощи оператора []

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string str("123");

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << str[i]  << ","; //1,2,3, 
    }
}
```

или итерторов

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string str("123");

    std::string::iterator begin = str.begin();
    std::string::iterator end = str.end();
    while(begin != end){
        std::cout << *begin  << ","; //1,2,3, 
        ++begin;
    }
}
```

**Преобразование символа char в число int**
В стандартной библиотеке C++ нет функции, которая выполняет такое преобразование, но её несложно написать самому

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int charToInt(char c){
    return c - '0';
}

int main(){
    char c = '9';
    int i = charToInt(c);
    std::cout << i << std::endl; //9
}
```

**Просуммировать все значения**
Можно сделать это вручную при помощи цикла. Но есть алгоритм из std, который может это сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

int charToInt(char c){
    return c - '0';
}
int add(int i, char c){
    return i + charToInt(c);
}


int main(){
    std::string str = "123";
    int summ = std::accumulate(str.begin(), str.end(), 0, add);
    std::cout << summ << std::endl; //6
}
```

Answer (score 5):

перевести число в строку:

```
std::string s = std::to_string(number); // требует C++11
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/

Если Вам нужна с-строка, то

```
const char buffer[80];
sprintf(buffer, "%d", number);
```

Получить числовое выражение символа цифры из символа:

```
int numeric_digit_value = char_digit_value - '0'; // гарантируется стандартом
```

Наоборот, из строки в число:

```
std::string string_value("42");
int numeric_value = std::stoi(string_value); // требует С++11
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

А вообще, чтобы получить сумму цифр, переводить число в строку не нужно

```
unsigned sum_of_digits(unsigned value) {
   unsigned sum = 0;
   while (value > 0) {
      sum += value % 10;
      value /= 10;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Не могу понять, как написать..подскажите. И к тому же, мне надо из строки в инт

Answer (score -1):

st - название строки.
chilso - название переменной.
`chislo = atof( st.c_str() );` - функция преобразующая строку в число atof - для float atoi - для int