# Проблема с выводом числа (С++)

Tags: c++, массивы

Пишу программу, которая должна считывать и выводить сумму, всех введенных в строку чисел.

Проблема с выводом, вместо того, чтобы выводить сумму значений введеных чисел, программа выводит сумму коддов клавиш этих же чисел. Сумму кодов клавиш соответствует сумме самих чисел.

Просьба, объяснить почему так выходит и как пофиксить вывод.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int Quan(string numb)
{
    return numb.length();
}

int Sum(string numb)
{
    int s = Quan(numb);
    int su = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        su += numb[i];
    }
    return su;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    string numb;
    cin >> numb;
    cout << Sum(numb);
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изьять из строки числа? С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550412/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%8c%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%a1)

Comment: [Преобразование char -> int цифры и буквы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470844), [Приведение char к int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1025076), [Как конвертировать символ в цифру?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/50533)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ни о какой сумме чисел в строке речь идти не может, потому что вы читаете в `numb` не строку, а слово - одно число. Так что можете просто написать

```
int numb;
cin >> numb;
cout << numb;
```

или

```
string numb;
cin >> numb;
cout << stoi(numb);
```

Чтобы делать то, что вы хотите -

```
string numb;
getline(cin,numb);
istringstream ss(numb);
int n,sum = 0;
while(ss >> n) sum += n;
cout << sum;
```